# Pinterest Code - How to open in a Pop up window

Tags: javascript, sharing, pinterest

I am new to all this coding stuff, so please take it easy on me...

Yesterday I spent hours finding and implementing a Pinterest Hover Sharing button on my blog. I finally managed to install it and understand the code. Anyway, the button shows fine and works, but I hate that when the button is clicked, it opens in a New Tab. I want it to open in a pop up window... Is it possible to make this happen?

Here is the code I am using, it is in my Blog's HTML area.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var bs_pinButtonURL = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-rwtYRUjgDok/UiJ-EfGfrbI/AAAAAAAAAXg/QXRpDUzaa6s/s1600/Pinterest+Red.png";
var bs_pinButtonPos = "topright";
var bs_pinPrefix = "";
var bs_pinSuffix = "";
//]]>
</script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script id='bs_pinOnHover' src='http://greenlava-code.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/publicscripts/bs_pinOnHoverv1_min.js' type='text/javascript'>
// Visit http://www.bloggersentral.com/2012/11/pinterest-pin-it-button-on-image-hover.html for details.
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me out, thanks..  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.

```
<div class="sprite pintrest-logo" onclick="window.open(
'//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=SITE_URL&amp;media=MEDIA_URL&amp;description=DESCRIPTION,
//'facebook-share-dialog', I honestly cannot remember if this is necessary and am not able to test currently. Will update when I find out
'width=750,height=288');    
return false;"></div>
```

Basically it takes the stuff that normally opens in a new tab, and instead opens it in a popup window

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me... And if i'm not mistaken your code here is "custom", meaning that i have to insert the Site URL and the description, but i want all that information to be automatically picked... 

As i said, i'm very new to codes. I even tried using your code here to see what it is, and i tried under the <head>, tried above </body>, and tried under <data:post.body/>, didn't work at all...

Comment: The important part is the onclick="...". That is what causes the new window. You should just put it on your button element. As for it being custom, I'm guessing that if you leave those fields out pintrist will auto generate them. not sure though

Comment: Well, i am not exactly sure which parts should i add from the code you wrote? And where exactly? You know well that every little dot and space counts... My button element, is that the first part or the second part of my code? Listen, i am very grateful for your help and i hate to ask you to "spoonfeed" me like this, but i don't really have a choice, i couldn't solve this myself, and i tried... Thanks  :)

Comment: Omg i don't know what happened, but i just looked at the original Code i wrote, and half of it is missing... Look at my code again please, i just edited it...